# What is wrong with this javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

ARGH! What's wrong with this??

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var monkeyTrouble = $('#monkeyTrouble').attr('rel');
  if (monkeyTrouble = "banana") {
    alert("oooh oooh ahh ahhh");
  }
});
```

Comment: Cheers all, stupidity from me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think you are looking for this...

```
if (monkeyTrouble == "banana") {
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

The condition is using `=`, should probably be `==`:

```
if (monkeyTrouble == "banana")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  if (monkeyTrouble == "banana") {
```

Comparing vs. assigning.

Answer (score 1):

well, if statement should be

```
if (monkeyTrouble == "banana")
```

note the "==".